# Python nltk RegexpTokenizer with all words and one specific phrase/chunk

Tags: python, regex, nltk

Is it possible to redefine a standard `nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer` to select all words as tokens and allow only one special phrase/chunk? For example, a standard setup would be:

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
```

Is it possible to allow, e.g., "big data" as a single token?

Comment: `tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\bbig\s+data\b|\w+')`?

Comment: Thanks [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew). Similarly, I could even do:
`tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\bsuper\s+big\s+data\b|\w+')`?

Answer (score 0):

The [`nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer.html)  is

> A tokenizer that splits a string using a regular expression, which matches either the tokens or the separators between tokens.

To actually match tokens, you must use `gaps=False`, as otherwise, it will act as a token separator.

So, to answer your question, you need to use something like

```py
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\bbig\s+data\b|\w+', gaps=False)
```

Now, the pattern inside will actually tokenize the text into either a whole word `big data` (with any amount of whitespaces between the two words) or any other one or more word chars.

Note that `\w` in Python 3.x `re` matches any Unicode letters, digits, connector punctuation and even some diacritics.

*Pattern details*

- `\b` - word boundary
- `big` - `big` string
- `\s+`  - one or more whitespaces
- `data` - a `data` string
- `\b` - word boundary
- `|` - or
- `\w+` - one or more letters/digits/connector punctuation or non-spacing mark (some diacritic) symbols.

Comment: Thanks again [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew), would you recommend something else, more explicit instead of `\w+`?

Comment: @striatum It depends on your requirements. `\w+` is generic. `[^\W\d_]+` will only match letters and some diacritics, so it is best to match just letter sequences.

Comment: So, then, should I go explicit `[a-zA-Z0-9]`?

Comment: @striatum No idea, `[a-zA-Z0-9]` does not match any "extended" Unicode letters, it does not match `ż`, for example. Again, I do not know your actual requirements.